# Vue: how to properly connect Pinia store, Router and UI toolbar for sharing a global state variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia

Given an app on Vue 3 and Quasar.
The app manages some configurations but only one at a time. So there's a notion of "current configuration" which is simply a string (name).
I want to have a dropdown in app's toolbar with all configurations where the current configuration selected as active). When it's selected it should be reflected in the URL params (like &config=name1) regardless of the current route. On application start if there's the config in the URL it should be parse and set as current configuration name.
But the router and toolbar's dropdown should work together but isolated. All other component should use a store's field `currentConfig`. The store is on Pinia.
That store's field should be connect to router:
when I change store.currentConfig it automatically changes the URL param and the toolbar
and the other way around: the currently selected config in the toolbar should be always reflected in store's field.

How to properly bound together all these three entities?

What I did.
In toolbar:

```
          <q-list>
            <q-item v-for="t in store.configs" :key="`${t.name}`" clickable v-close-popup tabindex="0"
              @click="store.currentConfig = t.name" :active="store.currentConfig == t.name">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label>{{ t.name }}</q-item-label>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
          </q-list>
```

i.e. on selecting a config we just set the store's field.

In my store (stores/configuration.ts) I have a state's field:

```
export const configurationStore = defineStore('configuration', {
  state: () => ({
    currentConfig: ''
  })
});
```

I want to react on its changes inside the store. And it seems that in such a handler it'd be a good place to pust the URL param.
But I can't see a way to subscribe to its iwn store's changes :(

Answer (score 1):

here is how I would do it :

```
// router/index.js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
{
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: () => import("../views/Home.vue"),
    props: (route) => ({ config: route.query.config || "" }), // Capture 'config' from URL
},
// Other routes
];

const router = createRouter({
history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
routes,
});

export default router;
```

then add pinia config like so:

```
// stores/configuration.ts
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useConfigurationStore = defineStore("configuration", {
state: () => ({
    currentConfig: "",
}),
actions: {
    setCurrentConfig(configName) {
    this.currentConfig = configName;
    },
},
});
```

then , Main Vue App: In your main Vue app, you can use a computed property to synchronize the store's state with the URL parameter. Additionally, use a watch to update the URL parameter when the store's currentConfig changes.

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import { useConfigurationStore } from "./stores/configuration";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);

const store = useConfigurationStore();

app.config.globalProperties.$store = store;

app.mount("#app");

// Synchronize store state with URL parameter
const configFromRoute = router.currentRoute.value.query.config;
if (configFromRoute) {
store.setCurrentConfig(configFromRoute);
}

// Watch for changes in the store's currentConfig and update the URL parameter
store.$watch(
(state) => state.currentConfig,
(newConfig) => {
    router.push({ query: { config: newConfig } });
}
);
```

then the fun part inside the dropdown component:

```
<!-- Dropdown.vue -->
<template>
<select v-model="currentConfig">
    <option v-for="config in configs" :key="config.name" :value="config.name">
    {{ config.name }}
    </option>
</select>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useConfigurationStore } from "@/stores/configuration";

export default {
name: "Dropdown",
setup() {
    const store = useConfigurationStore();
    const currentConfig = computed({
    get: () => store.currentConfig,
    set: (value) => store.setCurrentConfig(value),
    });

    const configs = [
    // Your list of configuration options
    ];

    return {
    currentConfig,
    configs,
    };
},
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't have $watch on my store (Pinia@2.0.36), did you mean $subscribe?